# continuity of linear operator with finite dimensional range

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X\rightarrow~Y$ be a linear operator s.t. $X$ is a Banach space and $Y$ is finite dimensional.
How can I prove that $T$ is a bounded linear operator.
I tried to prove when $X$ is a Hilbert space, but couldn't go far.

Comment: I think you want $X$ finite dimensional?

Comment: That's not true even if the dimension of $Y$ is $1$. If $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space there exist unbounded linear functionals on $X$.

Comment: yes $T$ may not be bounded. @DavidC.Ullrich.